# I cant see Block Editor with v5.7

Tags: block-editor

The Classic Editor plugin was used to disable Gutenberg on my site, by someone who was helping me.

The site was copied to another server and the Classic editor plugin was removed without switching back the setting. (Also the domain for the new server is different.)

I am using Divi, but want to edits posts with the Gutenberg editor

Not the site was stuck with the Classic editor

I reinstalled the plugin and switched back to the Block editor as the default.

But the change is ignored - I cannot access the block editor

Every time I edit layout a new custom field appears:  classic-editor-remember  value :classic editor. Even if I remove it, it comes back when I edit the page again.

Comment: Do you definitely have a recent enough Divi that supports Gutenberg? it might be doing the disabling. If you change themes can you re-enable Gutenberg? Are there any other plugins that might be disabling it?